# Invoke Apex Code from a Flow

Tags: apex, visual-flows

I am new to visual flow and i need some help on the Apex code from a flow and Process.Plugin .Actaully i have scenario where i need to create survey question and answer in visual flow using the Apex code and visual force page .

I am getting out of issues in the Apex class getting query from answer object .

Could you please help on this or provide me any guide or blogs which already been implemented in the projects

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you specifically need to use the `Process.Plugin` interface, but if you annotate your method with the `@InvocableMethod` annotation, you can call your Apex via Flow and via Process Builder (an added bonus).

There are some examples in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm):

```
public class AccountQueryAction {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Account Names' description='Returns the list of account names corresponding to the specified account IDs.')
  public static List<String> getAccountNames(List<ID> ids) {
    List<String> accountNames = new List<String>();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id in :ids];
    for (Account account : accounts) {
      accountNames.add(account.Name);
    }
    return accountNames;
  }
}
```